# Not able to render a group (list) of Text

Tags: react-native

I have an extremely simple React Native (Android) application as follows. Basically, I have a list of two to-do in the state, and I want to render them as consecutive `<Text>` elements:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            todos: [
                { id: 1, text: 'First todo' },
                { id: 2, text: 'Second todo' }
            ]
        };
    }

    render() {
        const items = this.state.todos.map((item) => {
            <Text>{item.text}</Text>
        });

        console.log(items);
        console.log(this.state.todos);

        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Total todos: {this.state.todos.length}</Text>
                {items}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The two `console.log` are fo debugging. What they output is:

```
Array [
  undefined,
  undefined,
]

Array [
  Object {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "First todo",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 2,
    "text": "Second todo",
  },
]
```

In other words, the `{items}` element is an array containing `undefined` (I don't know why), and consequently, when the app runs, all I see is:

`Total todos: 2`

Why are the two todos inside `state` not getting rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a return statement in your map and it should do the trick ;-)

```
const items = this.state.todos.map((item) => {
        return <Text>{item.text}</Text>
    });
```